# Scaffold-DbContext but can't search through database

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

.NET Core Used Scaffold-DbContext to import items but I can't search the items. [As seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lovuB.jpg), [or here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKjku.jpg), the command to find the "where" (or all other methods like ToList, FirstOrDefault) all do not work at all. These would normally work with [classess set as "DbSet"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wppTL.jpg). Why is it not working? I tried rebuilding the project as well. Any ideas?

Comment: You need `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Use `Ctrl + .` to get IntelliSense to suggest adding the namespaces that you are missing. For writing EF queries, you should have `using System.Linq` and `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`.

Comment: you can get an understanding on extension functions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods